# Remove line with one or two digits and space using php

Tags: php, regex, forms

I want to delete lines that contain only one digit, 2 digits, one digit a space one digit.

Ex:

```
text 1
1 text
11
1 0
111
1
```

Modified in:

```
text 1
1 text
111
```

My code is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    $text = $_POST["edit"];
    $text = preg_replace('/^\d{1,2}$/m', 'change', $text);
}
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input style="display:block;" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    <textarea name="edit" id="edit" cols="75" rows="30">
    </textarea>
    <textarea cols="75" rows="30">
        <?php echo $text; ?>
    </textarea>
</form>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cyba-98fj

The problem is that only the last line change that has a number or two.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
(?:^|\n)\d?\s?\d?(?=\n|$)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/iG0gT8/1)

```
(?:^|\n)      # at start or at new lines
\d?           # optional digit
\s?           # optional space
\d?           # optional digit
(?=\n|$)      # must be the end or a new line
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed. In my code does not work properly. Why? http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9z6m-tcqh

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multiline text, use

```
^\d(?:\h?\d)?$\n?
```

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of line
- `\d` - one digit
- `(?:\h?\d)?` - an optional (1 or 0 times) sequence of 1 or 0 horizontal whitespace (`\h?`) and a digit (`\d`)
- `$` - end of line
- `\n?` - optional newline symbol.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK8cO7/1)

```
$re = '/^\d(?:\h?\d)?$\n?/m'; 
$str = "text 1\n1 text\n11\n1 0\n111\n1"; 
echo $result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/7rBOiD)

Comment: Why is the `\n?` needed? I thought the `m` would separate each new line as its own.

Comment: It is used to remove the newline after the removed line, if the line is not the last one in the multiline string. Remove if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$text = <<< LOL
text 1
1 text
11
1 0
111
1 
LOL;
$text = preg_replace('/^(\d{1,2}|\d\s{1}\d?)$/sim', '', $text);
//remove blank lines
$text  = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text );

echo $text;
/*
text 1
1 text
111
*/
```

---

**DEMO**

http://ideone.com/THEkbz

---

**Regex Explanation**

```
^(\d{1,2}|\d\s{1}\d?)$

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Greedy quantifiers; Regex syntax only

Assert position at the beginning of a line «^»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d{1,2}|\d\s{1}\d?)»
   Match this alternative «\d{1,2}»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” «\d{1,2}»
         Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,2}»
   Or match this alternative «\d\s{1}\d?»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” «\d»
      Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” «\s{1}»
         Exactly once «{1}»
      Match a single character that is a “digit” «\d?»
         Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Assert position at the end of a line «$»
```